# DataSet Returned to JavaScript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to know how to get an object by position with AngularJS, I return from WebAPI in C# a DataSet with 4 DataTable and save it in a $scope on my JS, when i do `console.log($scope.data)` in the Chrome Console see like the image. Now when i do `console.log($scope.data[1])` in Chrome Console i get undefinided, but when i do `console.log($scope.data.inputs0)` i see the correct data. What is wrong? Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no $scope.data[1]. It's not an array, it's an object. You can do a few things :

1. use a js library like "Underscore.js" and use `_.findWhere($scope.data, {key : "someData"});` which will return the object at that key (this assumes you know the key name).
2. Loop through each set of inputs with an angular.ForEach. Ex:

   angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item, key){
       //Now something like $scope.data[0] is passed in essentially

   });

If you don't know the name of it, you won't be able to get it. You could also remap your object $scope.data to something more descriptive or to keys of 0, 1, 2 etc. Having them listed as you do probably isn't the best way to handle this.

Comment: And how to return an array  in c# to my js?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# really so I'm not sure how it interacts with JS directly. I know there is a way to return your C# object array to javascript. Try looking that portion up directly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i extract the key's names in an angular foreach and work with em.

```
angular.forEach($scope.dataInputs, function (value, key) {
    var nombrePos = key.slice(-1); //key=inputs0 and nombrePos=0
    ...
});
```